# Does the fsharp compiler reduce redundant function compositions to null operations?

Tags: f#, compiler-optimization

Does the following expression result in any code with the fsharp compiler?

```
let xs = List.rev <| List.rev xs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You can look at the output IL on [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNALiCWwA+wCmMAE8B2weozAwA8IMBeEspAPgwBl4IYA6AJ1QDcNaGnWOnALAAoUUA===) to verify what it will emit.

You can read about the kinds of optimizations to code the F# compiler does [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/docs/compiler-guide.md#code-optimizations). There are several things it optimizes with different techniques, some of which are better-documented than others.

Comment: I'm confused. The IL you linked to clearly shows two calls to `[FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule::Reverse`

Comment: I think I understand now - you were answering the question's title, rather than the text in the question. So, just to be clear, the F# compiler does *not* optimize away this particular expression.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wasn't sure how to put it exactly.